# Raspberry pi can not receive a SIGNAL while on ubuntu machine it can, Qt program

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, raspberry-pi3

I've set two pairs of SIGNAL/SLOT but those SIGNAL/SLOT only work on my ubuntu machine, not working on pi 3.

I was using a ubuntu desktop PC with a raspberry pi 3 to lean qt development and also some basic about cross compiling. After few days's struggle I finally made some examples run on raspberry pi and looks all good. So I wrote a UART receiving program on Ubuntu, compile and run on raspberry pi.

Only three .cpp file was in the project, which are

```
main.cpp // main
mainwindow.cpp // Qt widget
uartthread.cpp // thread to process UART reading
```

main.cpp is quite simple only few lines:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;

w.show();

return a.exec();
```

and in the mainwindows I have set a text browser to display any data received on uartthread, and 2 buttons that can stop/resume receiving. Also a private variable was declared to store the receiving status. Their relation can be illustrate in the declaration under mainwindow.h as shown below:

```
private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
bool Stop = false; // store the receiving status

QThread *muartThread = new QThread(this); // QThread later for movetothread

uartThread *uartobj = new uartThread(); // uart obj create, later moveto QThread
```

Then, while a button pressed, a signal will emit, handled in uartthread afterwards.

```
 void MainWindow::on_stop_but_clicked()
 {  
　　　　// stop display
    QMutex stopMutex;

    stopMutex.lock();
    Stop = true;
    stopMutex.unlock();

    emit stopButton();

    qDebug() << "Stop button pressed, Stop = true!" << endl;
}

 void MainWindow::on_recei_but_clicked()
 {   QMutex stopMutex;

    stopMutex.lock();
    Stop = false;
    stopMutex.unlock();

    emit receivButton();

    qDebug() << "Receive button pressed, Stop = false!" << endl;
}
```

And those two signals was registered in MainWindow constructor as:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(receivButton()),uartobj,SLOT(receive_press()));
connect(this,SIGNAL(stopButton()),uartobj,SLOT(stop_press()));
```

In this case, the private variables declare in uartthread can be modified.

Then I compile those code under ubuntu machine with raspi-kit, 0 issues, but when I run the program, it never reach the SLOTS. However, when I compile the code with ubuntu-kit, when ever I press the button, the press singal can always be handle.

Below are some additional information:

```
Ubuntu: 
Ubuntu 16.04
Desktop Qt 5.6.1 GCC64

pi 3:
Raspbian 8.0
Qt 5.6.2
```

Comment: How do you check if the slot is called? Do you run it in a debugger or do you look for the debug output via qDebug()?

Comment: Off topic but... your `stopMutex` variables are locally scoped with automatic storage so they don't actually perform any useful purpose (as far as I can see).

Comment: @PaulR. I have a qDebug output in slot function.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for your advise, I follow a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WEiQ3VJfxc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63&index=30) and this is how that guy use Mutex. I'll check qt official tutorial carefully, and again, appreciate for your correction.

Comment: Do you see the output from the button functions? If not, you should run your program in a debugger. It might happen that  the qDebug() output does not end up where you expect it to end up. Running the program in a debugger is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @PaulR. Hi Paul, I have set a qdebug output on push button signal and another output in the handle slot. However, the output from signal can always generate, the slot one never worked on pi environment...

Answer (score 0):

**1st Attempt** (Failed)

I've change

d the signal to

```
 void stopConditionButton(int);
```

and slot to:

```
 void stopConditionButton_slot(int);
```

using the parameter to state the button condition, and now the
raspberry pi can work properly. Not sure what cause the original
problem, but this seems a way out.

After few hours work now this approach doesn't work anymore... I didn't use any version control tools so I'll try to comment away codes added and see whether I can get back to the right track.

**2nd Attempt**(Failed)

Okay, so after some reading and re-write the thread make it looks properly from link https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage. Also that the connect method will return a QMetaObject::Connection that represents a handle which can be cast to bool to indicate a connection established result. Sad thing is all doesn't work. Thread works perfectly well and the connection is solid established. Got some thoughts from @Tyler, I'll focus on the compiling fail.

Comment: That would make me think it's not getting processed by `moc`. You need to use `qmake` to build the project on the rpi and you won't have to add the `_slot` yourself.

Comment: Read about building Qt projects from the command line. It's not as simple as just passing them to `g++`. They need to be preprocessed first. That's what `moc` is for. Using `qmake` will generate a `makefile` which will coordinate all this for you.

Comment: @Tyler Thanks for your advise, I'll give it a try. I only use the 'build' button in qt creator with all kits set. The reference I looked while build qt for pi is at: https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS . Is it the right way?